# Traversing a binary tree using a vector return type

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am trying to traverse a templated AVLtree with a key value pair and return a vector of all the values.

When using a cout statement, I can tell that the function is correctly traversing the tree and it will return all values in the tree. However, when I try to add this to a vector and use it in another part of my program, only the root node has been stored.

```
    vector<s> treeTraversal(){
         return treeTraversal(root);
    }

    vector<s> treeTraversal(AVLNode<t, s> *node ){
        vector<s> temp;

        if(node != nullptr){
            treeTraversal(node -> left);
            treeTraversal(node -> right);
            temp.push_back(node -> vectorToBe);
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

I am intending to store all the returned values in a vector so I can access them in a later part of my program

Comment: Do you see calls to `treeTraversal` where the value returned is outright ignored?  Make the function `[[nodiscard]]` and your mistakes will reported to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this. You'll avoid creating a ton of `vector<s>`s in the stack.

```
vector<s> treeTraversal(){
     vector<s> result;
     treeTraversal(root, result);
     return result;
}

void treeTraversal(AVLNode<t, s> *node, vector<s>& visited ){
    if(node != nullptr){
        treeTraversal(node -> left, visited);
        treeTraversal(node -> right, visited);
        visited.push_back(node->vectorToBe);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
treeTraversal(node -> left);
```

This recursively calls the function, this is one of the two recursive calls. Your `treeTraversal()` function returns a vector. However, here, its return values is thrown away and not stored anywhere.

```
return temp;
```

This is the vector that your function `return`s. However, as we've seen, it does not include anything that was returned from any recursive calls, because those returned values are thrown away and get ignored.

There are two usual ways to fix this:

1. Do not ignore the returned vector from both recursive calls. Store them, then append their contents to `temp`.
2. Instead of returning the `std::vector` make it an additional parameter to the recursive call. Each recursive call simply appends its value to the passed-in vector (and forwards it to any subsequent recursive calls). The caller of your recursive function will be responsible for instantiating an initially-empty vector, and passing it in.

Comment: I just noticed my solution is explicitly mentioned in your #2 bullet. :/ My bad.